# Windows 10 Home WiFi 'Destination Host Unreachable' when site IP starts with anything above 200

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ping, hosts

First of all I AM NOT A PROFESSIONAL - one would say a bit more experienced newbie girl, so please bear with me, though I have some knowledge that enables me at least testing + english is not my native language.

I have 2 different notebooks with Windows 10 Home x64 that normally connects to internet via WiFi over my home LAN thru a TP-LINK TL-WR710N router that basically only works as a switch (it does not route anything, DHCP is off, it only connects several PCs via WiFi to LAN so all the machine needs to have set their IP/DNS manually first).

Whenever I try to open any page which IP starts with number that is 200 or more (like 217.100.25.1, or 241.17.12.45 etc.) it will never be opened, but strangely enough if I connect those notebooks with LAN cable it can open all web pages I load! For instance it can open localized Google search engine of www.google.sk (172.217.23.227) but not its home of www.google.com (216.58.201.110)!

When I ping such sites I always get 'Destination Host Unreachable'.

I did all the things I already found on internet (none of them helped):

- Setting startup of OS as NORMAL via msconfig
- Cleared IP cache via cmd (`ipconfig /flushdns`)
- Reset TCP/IP settings (`netsh winsock reset`)
- Checking the Hosts File (`Notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`)
- Checked with Antivirus
- Check the system for loaded dll modules, registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows` - Applnit_DLLs entry)
- Cleared the Routing Table (`route –f`)
- Checked Firewall settings if it does not block those sites

This is the WiFi adapter settings - I have STATIC IP for all my LAN PCs so I could find them specifically everytime, so it is like:

- SSID: name-of-my-WIFI-here
- Protocol: 802.11n
- Encryption: WPA2-Personal
- Frequency: 2.4 GHz
- IPv4: 192.168.1.51
- IPv4 DNS: 192.168.1.10
- WIFI module: Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter
- Driver version: 3.0.2.201

Overall I would say it is something specific in these notebook WiFi modules because all of our smartphones connect to any site on our LAN with no problem - this is specific to WiFi on Windows 10 HOME only...

Comment: Is the barrier _exactly_ at 200.x? Could you include the output of `tracert -d <addr>` for some of those addresses? That is, is the OS itself rejecting them, or is it coming from a router along the path? (Also, what netmask / prefix length is configured – is it the usual /24 or something else?)

Comment: @grawity tracert -d google.com 1. 192.168.1.51: reports: Destination host unreachable {192.168.1.51 is the notebook itself}, "what netmask / prefix length is configured" - how can I found out this, please? I would know how to find it in Win7, Win10 is terrible as to find what-is-where, on Win7 I always have it like 255.255.255.0, and never had any problem whatsoever + it cannot be router cos it allows load those sites for Android smartphones as I said in my post

Comment: @grawity aaah, I guess I found it by looking into smartphone (Android) WiFi settings of my wifi connection comparing it to both Win10 notebooks: on Android it was set to 24, but on notebooks it was 2 and 3 respectively! Once I set those to 24 it seems it works as expected...at last so far (1 day)